# How to call reloaddata() from another class?

Tags: swift, macos, delegates, nstableview

I have two classes `NSViewController`, which contains a `NSTableView`, and a `NSPageController`, which can be used to add data to the table view. How can I call `reloadData()` from `NSPageController` to update the table view of `NSViewController`?

**Update:**

I already tried to solve this with a delegate and I already have done this in Objective-C, but with swift I feel completely lost.

My PageController needs to notify the ViewController, that the tableView has to be updated. So I added this code to my PageController

```
protocol PageControllerDelegate {
    func updateTableView()
}
```

and

```
weak var delegate: PageControllerDelegate?
```

To my ViewController which hold the table view I added the following lines:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, PageControllerDelegate {
...
```

and

```
func updateTableView() {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Xcode gives me the following errors:

- 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'PageControllerDelegate'
- Property 'delegate' with type 'PageControllerDelegate?' cannot override a property with type 'NSPageControllerDelegate?' (aka 'Optional')

Comment: A notification?  A reference, and method call?  KVO?  It's a bit hard to give concrete advice without any source code.

Answer (score 2):

I can give you only a generic answer.

First of all, you need a contact for your view controllers. Like `NSTableViewController` or something that you defined (a Protocol).

Example, when you using a table view controller:

```
(viewController as? NSTableViewController)?.tableView.reloadData()
```

And an example, when you using a view controller with an contract:

The contact:

```
protocol HasTableView {
    var tableView: NSTableView? { get }
}
```

The view controller conforming to the contract:

```
class ExampleViewController: NSViewController, HasTableView {
    var tableView: NSTableView? { return myTableView }
    ...
}
```

And your reload data call:

```
(viewController as? HasTableView)?.tableView?.reloadData()
```

Hope it’s helps.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do, depending on your control hierarchy - if your `NSViewControllers` hold your controller, then give our controller class a `weak var delegate: NSViewControllerDelegate`, and define a `protocol

```
NSViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
   func controllerShouldUpdateTableView(_ controller: NSController)
}
```

have your `NSViewController` conform to this protocol, and then make sure set the delegate on the controller. Just call this function when needed to reload your table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for my short question in the first place. I want to solve this with a delegate, but I must do something wrong. So I tried it again with the help of your answer, but I get some errors (see updated question).

Comment: Hey - try subclassing `PageControllerDelegate` from `AnyObject` - 
       `PageControllerDelegate: AnyObject`

Comment: Thanks. When I write `protocol MyPageControllerDelegate: AnyObject {func updateTableData()}` I still get the error: `Property 'delegate' with type 'MyPageControllerDelegate?' cannot override a property with type 'NSPageControllerDelegate?' (aka 'Optional<NSPageControllerDelegate>')`